# pulseaudio volume change not effecting in HSP/HFP mode

Tags: pulseaudio, headset

I am using airpods with ofono-phonesim on ubuntu
It's working fine in A2DP profile mode. I can change volume.
But in HSP/HFP mode volume change is not effecting but it's showing updated volume in pactl info.

> debug information:

pulseaudio:

```
Sink #1
    State: IDLE
    Name: bluez_sink.4C_6B_E8_80_46_A4.headset_head_unit
    Description: Akhil’s AirPods
    Driver: module-bluez5-device.c
    Sample Specification: s16le 1ch 8000Hz
    Channel Map: mono
    Owner Module: 23
    Mute: no
    Volume: mono: 16379 /  25%
            balance 0.00
    Base Volume: 65536 / 100%
    Monitor Source: bluez_sink.4C_6B_E8_80_46_A4.headset_head_unit.monitor
    Latency: 30655 usec, configured 28000 usec
    Flags: HARDWARE HW_VOLUME_CTRL LATENCY 
    Properties:
        bluetooth.protocol = "headset_head_unit"
        device.intended_roles = "phone"
        device.description = "Akhil’s AirPods"
        device.string = "4C:6B:E8:80:46:A4"
        device.api = "bluez"
        device.class = "sound"
        device.bus = "bluetooth"
        device.form_factor = "headphone"
        bluez.path = "/org/bluez/hci0/dev_4C_6B_E8_80_46_A4"
        bluez.class = "0x240418"
        bluez.alias = "Akhil’s AirPods"
        device.icon_name = "audio-headphones-bluetooth"
    Ports:
        headphone-output: Headphone (priority: 0, available)
    Active Port: headphone-output
    Formats:
        pcm
```

ofono

```
[ /phonesim ]
    Online = 0
    Powered = 1
    Lockdown = 0
    Emergency = 0
    Manufacturer = MeeGo
    Model = Synthetic Device
    Revision = REV1
    Serial = 1234567890
    Interfaces = org.ofono.SmartMessaging org.ofono.PushNotification org.ofono.MessageManager org.ofono.Phonebook org.ofono.TextTelephony org.ofono.RadioSettings org.ofono.CallForwarding org.ofono.SimToolkit org.ofono.SimAuthentication org.ofono.AllowedAccessPoints org.ofono.VoiceCallManager org.ofono.SimManager 
    Features = sms tty rat stk sim 
    Type = hardware
    [ org.ofono.SmartMessaging ]
    [ org.ofono.PushNotification ]
    [ org.ofono.MessageManager ]
        ServiceCenterAddress = +15551234567
        UseDeliveryReports = 0
        Bearer = cs-preferred
        Alphabet = default
    [ org.ofono.Phonebook ]
    [ org.ofono.TextTelephony ]
        Enabled = 1
    [ org.ofono.RadioSettings ]
        TechnologyPreference = any
        AvailableTechnologies = gsm umts lte 
    [ org.ofono.CallForwarding ]
        VoiceUnconditional = 
        VoiceBusy = 
        VoiceNoReply = 
        VoiceNoReplyTimeout = 20
        VoiceNotReachable = 
        ForwardingFlagOnSim = 0
    [ org.ofono.SimToolkit ]
        IdleModeText = 
        IdleModeIcon = 
        MainMenuTitle = 
        MainMenuIcon = 
        MainMenu = 
    [ org.ofono.SimAuthentication ]
        NetworkAccessIdentity = 12345678@phonesim.org
    [ org.ofono.AllowedAccessPoints ]
    [ org.ofono.VoiceCallManager ]
        EmergencyNumbers = 911 1020 112 
    [ org.ofono.SimManager ]
        Present = 1
        CardIdentifier = 8949222074451242066
        SubscriberIdentity = 246813579
        ImsPrivateIdentity = 12345678@phonesim.org
        FixedDialing = 0
        BarredDialing = 0
        MobileCountryCode = 246
        MobileNetworkCode = 81
        SubscriberNumbers = 358501234567 
        LockedPins = 
        ServiceNumbers = [112] = '112' [Emergency] = '999' [Police] = '997' [Firemen] = '998' [Sea emergency] = '+48601100100' [Mountain emer.] = '+48601100300' [.HELP DESK] = '2601' [.RECHARGE] = '5555' [.Voicemail] = '+48601222222' [.Voice access] = '+48601104444' 
        PreferredLanguages = de en it fr es nl 
        PinRequired = none
        Retries = [pin = 3] 
        CardSlotCount = 1
        ActiveCardSlot = 1
```

Update 1:
I am able to change volume in HSP/HFP mode also now, in application profile. ie: chrome volume.